# Type is not defined error seen in javascript when ajax toolkit is removed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, javascript-objects

My javascript file references [MicrosoftAjax.js](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.js) to register the namespace and classes using registerNamespace and registerClass functions  like this :

```
    //Registering the namespace 'Root' using MS Ajax Framework
  if (typeof (Root) == 'undefined') {
    Type.registerNamespace('Root');
 }
```

The Root namespace is referenced at multiple places in the javascript file like :

```
Root.__ServiceInstances = new Object();

Root.StringDictionary = function() {
    this._arrDictionary = new Object();
}

Root.StringDictionary.registerClass('Root.StringDictionary', null);

Root.KeyedItemDictionary = function() {
    this._arrDictionary = new Object();
}

//Registering the class
Root.KeyedItemDictionary.registerClass('Root.KeyedItemDictionary', null);
```

I do not want to use Ajax longer in my project.
When I removed the reference to MicrosoftAjjax.js from my javascript file, I recieved 'Type is not defined' error.

Is there any workaround I can do in javascript file itself to register the namespaces and classes without Microsoft Ajax framework.

Please know that I am primarily a .NET dev and a beginner in javascript. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, one would assume that you added the ajaxtoolkit via nuget. So, should one then now remove the nuget package from the project?

Of course any page that you tested or adopted a extender or aj control, then at the top of that page, you see this:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
  namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

So, removing the above from the given pages (and any aj control or extender tags) should thus result in the aj toolkit having been removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am only using the MicrosoftAjax.js and not using the entire toolkit, I was successfully able to remove the MicrosoftAjax.js reference. My question is particular to resolving the errors by registering the namespace in javascript code. I am new to javascript.